# Error: The label ... already occurs in this switch statement

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

My switch case has an error:

> Error: The label case 1 already occurs in this switch statement

```
switch (myEnum)
{
    case MyEnum.EnumOne:
        break;
    case MyEnum.EnumTwo:
        break;
    case MyEnum.EnumThree: //The error line
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figure it out:

My enum definition of `EnumThree` is wrong:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    EnumOne = 0,
    EnumTwo = 1,
    EnumThree = 1,
}
```

Iv'e edited `MyEnum` definition to (thanks @dmitry-bychenko):

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    None = 0
    EnumOne = 1,
    EnumTwo = 2,
    EnumThree = 3,
}
```

And it worked.

Comment: Or remove the number assignment from the enum

Comment: May be `None = 0, EnumOne = 1, EnumTwo = 2, EnumThree = 3` is a better (more readable) choice: name corresponds its value